# How to use an array as a dependency of a React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that has a callback.  It depends on an array of plain old objects stored in redux which won't change very often while the component itself *will* change its state pretty frequently.  Some subcomponents should be rerendered on those state changes, but the one that uses the callback, should not.

What's the best approach to making an array a dependency of `useCallback()`?  So far, I've been using

```js
const handleAllItemsSelectedChange = useCallback(
  checked => {
    if (checked) {
      dispatch(setSelected(items));
    } else {
      dispatch(selectSelected([]));
    }
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  [JSON.stringify(items)]
);
```

This doesn't seem ideal, and potentially slower than just rerendering the component every time.  I can't imagine this isn't a very common use-case.  The React team surely has a best practice for this, right?  I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` or any deep comparison is going to be inefficient and slow. [React has no plans to support it](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055)

Depending on whether you add or remove items (if not mutating the objects) you can just compare with `items.length`. Or you could possibly save performance by just creating the function each time, as opposed to trying to *save* performance putting it in a `useCallback`.

It's a case by case scenario

Answer (score 0):

In redux reducer every time the array changes you have to create new array. So, your array becomes immutable and you can use it for dependency by reference. Example below just demonstrates the principle.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "addItem":
            return {...state, items: [...state.items, action.value]};
        case "changeProp":
            return {...state, prop: action.value}
        default:
            return state;
     }
 }
```

As you can see every time the array changes you'll get the new instance of the array. That means you can use it by reference and don't need to strignify it anymore:

```
 const handleAction = useCallback(checked=>{
      ....
 }, [items]);
```

By the way immutability is the approach recommended by redux documentation

Comment: In general, yes.  This array was actually generated via a calculation on the items in the store.

Comment: I think my frustration is that if I have 1000 objects in an array and I change one of those objects, I have to create a new array which causes the entire item container to rerender any child component that uses a callback rather than just the component attached to the object that was edited.  If my callback only needs to update when one specific property of each item changes (`obj.selected`, in this case), and a different property of the object is changed, there's no reason to recreate the callback, which rerenders my entire 3rd party grid.